# Troubleshooting "unhandled exception in thread" error

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7

When I execute this code

```
import class3,thread

t3 = class3.test3
thread.start_new_thread(t3.func3,())
```

where `class3` is

```
class test3(object):
    def func3():
        while 1:
            print "working!!"
```

I get an error:

> Unhandled exception in thread started by <unbound method test3.func3>

What is the meaning of this error, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Call it and see what happens:

```
TypeError: unbound method func3() must be called with test3 instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

You either have to make `func3` an instance method and initialize your class:

```
class test3(object):
        def func3(self):
            while True:
                print "working!!"

t3 = test3()
```

Or make `func3` a `staticmethod`:

```
class test3(object):
    @staticmethod
    def func3():
        while True:
            print "working!!"
```